# swift Dynamic Modify frame and remove AutoLayout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, swift2

I dynamically modify a UILabel frame, each time the program starts UILabel modify my position, but the network data requests received after update to the UI, the modified UILabel with autoLayout returned to the original position.

**Code:**

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
self.label.removeConstraints(self.label.constraints)
}
```

but still not working

Thank attention

Answer (score 0):

```
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
self.label.updateConstraints()
}
```